# NodeJS socket.io несколько инстансов

Tags: socket.io

Добрый день. На сервере работает js скрипт, используется socket.io, транспорт flashsocket . Хочу запустить несколько инстансов на разных портах. Из этого вытекает два вопроса:
 1. Правильно ли оставлять flash policy server включенным лишь для одного инстанса? Т.к. когда включены у других возникает ошибка EADDRINUSE . При включенном у одного инстанса всё работает.
 2. Т.к. инстансов больше одного включил RedisStore . Значит ли это, что код

```
io.sockets.sockets[to].emit('private_message',message);
```

отработает верно, то есть айди сокета известен в любом инстансе? Что будет, например, если клиент подсоединён к инстансу 1, а во втором инстансе вы вызовем предыдущий код с айди сокета клиента, который присоединен к первому инстансу?

Answer (score 1):

Касательно второго под-вопроса:

```
io.sockets.sockets[to].emit('private_message',message);
```

Здесь `[to]` должен быть **ID** сокета конкретного юзера, т-е для каждого подсоединившегося юзера создается как бы отдельный поток со своим уникальным ID_SOCKET.